# How to use verilog module with adjacent underscore identifiers in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have a verilog module from an external vendor. I would like to wrap it in VHDL.

The problem is that the verilog module contains identifiers that have adjacent underscores in their names. VHDL seems not to allow this. Surely I can wrap the verilog module into another verilog module and then wrap it into a VHDL module, but isn't there a way to avoid it?

I wrote a small example to illustrate:

Verilog:

```
module underscore (

  test__in,
  test__out

);

input test__in;
output test__out;

assign test__out = test__in;

endmodule
```

VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_underscore is
end entity;

architecture rtl of tb_underscore is

 signal test_in: std_logic;
 signal test_out: std_logic;

begin

  i_underscore: entity work.underscore port map (

      test__in => test_in,
      test__out => test_out

    );


end architecture;
```

The VHDL code does not compile because of the adjacent underscores.

Comment: it's not a bug of the simulator tool, VHDL is defined like this by the LRM.

Comment: There are other classes of name incompatibility between Verilog and VHDL as well.  VHDL is not case sensitive for basic identifiers which also must begin with a letter and end with a letter or a number. Note that an extended identifier can have any graphic character between two escaped backslashes unlike SystemVerilog's escaped identifiers which end upon reaching white space.

Comment: You will likely need to create a verilog wrapper file to to handle the conversion. The iteration between VHDL and Verilog (or any two languages) must use conventions that are shared between the two languages. If it gets to more messy rules, like extended identifiers, you may need to create a wrapper on both sides to get commonality.